# Apple Mach-O Linker Error when Facebook installed using pods in the project

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, linker-errors

I have just installed the Facebook using pods and now my project is not working and says. Please help someone.

```
 Apple Mach-O Linker Error
 ld: 87 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**duplicate symbols for architecture** means your files are doubled, Please check if you have added facebook framework manually before using pods
you can also check files duplicating by seeing whole description of error

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

You need to do this:

Click on your project (targets) Click on Build Settings Under Library Search Paths, delete the paths May be this will help you.

**Solution 2**

You have duplicate symbol method which means there are duplicate file in project

In your Target's Build Phase, under "Compile Sources" check if there are duplicate file and delete one if you have duplication.

Hope this will help you.